# Multiway Cut Q- How do we show the solution in polymonial time?

Tags: algorithm

In the multiway cut problem, the input is an undirected graph G= (V, E) and set of terminal nodes s1, s2....sk are in V.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework, but here's a hint off the top of my head: If you turn your graph into a flow network in which every edge has a capacity of 1 and use the two terminal nodes as source and sink, you can use Edmonds-Karp to find the flow between the two terminal nodes in polynomial time. When you have found the maximum flow, what does the *min-cut max-flow theorem* tell you?

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is indeed solveable by min-cut max flow as sugesred by @Aasmund Eldhuset, the min cut between S1,S2 is actually the minimal set of edges you need to remove in order to seperate S1 and S2.

   Remember that the min cut problem says:

   > Given a graph (weighted, but you can use `w(e)=1` for all edges for
   >   the unweigted version), find the set of edges with combined minimal weight - such that the source (S1) and sink (S2) will be in different connected components.

   Note that this problem is exactly your problem - and is solveable by some algorithms such as [Edmond Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) - which runs in polynomial time
2. By repeating the process for (S1,S2) and (S2,S3) you get 2 sets of edges E1 (for S1,S2) and E2 (for S2,S3).

   Now, note that the optimal solution (let it be OPT) is not smaller then both E1 and E2 (otherwise - since the "cut" by OPT seperates S1,S2 and S2,S3 - it would have been returned as the answer instead of E1 or E2.

   From this we can conclude `|OPT| >= max{|E1|,|E2|}`. Note that `|E1 Union E2| <= |E1| + |E2| <= |OPT| + |OPT| = 2|OPT|` - thus `E1 Union E2` is a 2-approximation to the poblem.

Comment: Can you explain how it can be solved by min cut max flow for part a? I know what it is but I can't seem to apply it to solve it.